# convert information of struct of an pointer to array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, matrix, struct

I have a problem with a for loop, which should put information of struct of a pointer to an array. This struct is for complex numbers. The problem is the numbers m[n].re/.im -they are not korrekt.

```
typedef struct
{
  float re, im;
} Complex;

#define N 2
#define M 2

int main()
{
Complex* p;
Complex matrix[N][M]; //already filled
Complex m[N*M];
int n;

n = 0;
p = NULL;

for(p = &matrix[0][0]; p<= &matrix[0][0]+N*M-1; p++)
    {
        m[n] = *p;
        n = n+1;
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) use standard types! C has `_Complex` already (although it is optional - check you compiler). 2) there is a reason for types. Why not properly index the 2D array in both dimensions? 3) do not use single letter macro names. What is wrong e.g with `ROWS`? 4) using the same letter just with different case is bad style already. Using them for unrelated items is worse.

Comment: Why the comment "already filled"?  `Complex matrix[N][M];` is not initialized.

Comment: Basically, I think that  your code is no problem. [DEMO](http://ideone.com/wMetFk) it will work as expected.
(Special case of 2D-Array except  such as include those unnecessary)

Answer (score 1):

You can use standard C function `memcpy` declared in header `<string.h>` for example

```
memcpy( m, matrix, N * M * sizeof( Complex ) );
```

If you want to use a loop that uses pointers then it can look for example the following way

```
for ( Complex *q = ( Complex * )matrix, *p = m; q != ( Complex * )matrix + N * M; p++, q++ )
{
    *p = *q;
}
```

Comment: Проблема в том, что указатель используется в подпрограмме(я сократил текст тут). Так бы использовал первый вариант.
А второй я не совсем понял, к сожалению.

Comment: @Wildcoon Второй вариант - это, фактически, копия вашего варианта, только вместо переменной индекса n, я использую еще один указатель. Возможно ваша проблема состоит в том, что после копирования указатель p нужно снова установить на первый элемент массива.

Comment: @Wildcoon si fueris Rōmae, Rōmānō vīvitō mōre; si fueris alibī, vīvitō sicut ibi ‎

Comment: Второй вариант смог бы сработать, но у меня нет на самом деле matrix в том месте - есть только указатель на её адрес. Я сократил тектс кода, там на самом деле беда в подпрограмме, которая получает только адрес первого элемента matrix. Из-за этого и весь конфуз.

Comment: @Wildcoon Не видя кода, который воспроизводит ошибку, трудно что-либо сказать.

Answer (score 1):

I've modified your program to initialize the matrix array, and to print to stdout the values of matrix and the array m after the copy using the for loop:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct
{
  float re, im;
} Complex;

#define N 2
#define M 2

int main()
{
    Complex* p;
    Complex matrix[N][M]; //already filled
    Complex m[N*M];
    int idx, jdx, val = 1;
    for (idx = 0; idx < N; idx++) {
            for (jdx = 0; jdx < M; jdx++) {
                    matrix[idx][jdx].re = val;
                    matrix[idx][jdx].im = val;
                    ++val;
            }
    }
    int n;

    n = 0;
    p = NULL;

    for (p = &matrix[0][0]; p < &matrix[0][0] + N*M; p++)
    {
            printf("matrix[%d] = %f + %fi\n", n, p->re, p->im);
            m[n] = *p;
            n = n+1;
    }

    int midx = 0;
    for (midx = 0; midx < N*M; midx++) {
            printf("m[%d] = %f + %fi\n", midx, m[midx].re, m[midx].im);
    }
    return 0;
```

}

I'm not sure what happened but to me it just looks like you didn't initialize the arrays. Remember, memcpy is your friend. Hope this code helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think the pointer `p` holds the address of a `struct Complex`. Not sure but try once like this

```
for(p = &matrix[0][0]; p<= &matrix[0][0]+N*M-1; p = p + sizeof(int))
    {
        m[n] = *p;
        n = n+1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way to do the copy is with `memcpy`, but if you want to use a loop, the code should look like this

```
Complex matrix[N][M];
Complex array[N*M];

Complex *p = array;
for ( int n = 0; n < N; n++ )
    for ( int m = 0; m < M; m++ )
        *p++ = matrix[n][m];
```

---

In response to the comment, given only a pointer to the matrix, and knowing the dimensions, it's possible to create a pointer that acts like a two dimensional array.

```
void someFunction( Complex *matrix, int sizeN, int sizeM )
{
    Complex (*p)[sizeM] = (void *)matrix;

    for ( int n = 0; n < sizeN; n++ )
        for ( int m = 0; m < sizeM; m++ )
            printf( "%f %f\n", p[n][m].re, p[n][m].im );
}
```

Comment: I can't use matrix anymore - that's the problem. I should put her the whole code - I cut lots of things, because it was too long. Actually I have a subroutine, where i get only the first address of the matrix from main. That's why I stuck on this cinvertion of a pointer to array.

Comment: @Wildcoon Ok, now I understand. I tried translating the comments under Vlad's answer, but the google translation was not very good.

Comment: thanks a lot for helping me! I have to work on this later - it's already night here =)